# Unique variable names in a for loop using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have 10 lists and want to perform same process on all of them and like to have unique name of all variables. Here is what I have:

```
for i in xrange(1,11,1):
    m + str(i) = np.array(m + str(i)).astype(np.float)
```

It throws syntax error:

```
Can't assign to operator(mean.py,line30)
```

Comment: You can't assign to an arbitrary expression, only names (`x`) and indexed expressions (`x[1]` for lists, `x['foo']` for dicts).

Comment: @Hackaholic: a variable name as I would like to save all lists with names `m1`, `m2`.....

Comment: Don't use multiple similarly named variables; use a single list `m`.

Comment: Or use a single multi-dimensional array. Depending on what your data looks like, that might be more appropriate.

Comment: Whenever you find yourself using sequentially numbered variables, you should probably be using an array/list instead. This is true for almost all programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `m1` et al., use a single list `m`.

```
m = [ ... ]
for i in xrange(1,11,1):
    m[i] = np.array(m[i]).astype(np.float)
```

Comment: at start list m is empty, so you might get `list index out of range`

Comment: `m` should be created as the collection of individual variables; `m = [m1, m2, m3]`.

Comment: What is `list + str(i)` supposed to be? If you already have `m1` et al. defined, you can literally just write `m = [m1, m2, m3]` to create the list. Ideally, though, you get rid of those variables and define `m` in terms of whatever you used to set the individual variables

Comment: Add an example of how you set the individual variables to your question.

Comment: I created `m` as list of lists and used above. It worked. Thanks!